# how to retrieve data from .dat file using hash map in java only

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `ratings.dat` file. It contains 5 fields. They are userid, movieid, rating, age, moviename. movieid is unique 1 to 3450. userid 1 to 6400. rating is given out of 5.

1. I want to load the file into a hash map, check for the conditions which is movie is having ratings > 3
2. Top 10 movies viewed by users
3. I want to sort the top 20 movies by the condition that users who have viewed at least 20 movies from them I want to select the top 20 movies.

I should not use SQL. I want 100% Java code. I have done till now: reading a file in hashmap and printing the content of that file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Output{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    HashMap< Integer, String > hash = new HashMap< Integer, String >();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new FileReader ("resources/ratings.dat"));
    String line = "::";

    int i = 0;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
        hash.put(i, line);
        i++;
    }
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < hash.size() ; j++){ 
        System.out.println(hash.get(j));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try something on your own to fail and learn. You've just done half of your assignment and probably passing on the other half here. Attempt once is what I would suggest.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to use a `HashMap`? Asking because to me it doesn’t seem like the best choice.

Comment: Since I don’t know the format of the lines of your `.dat` file, I have no idea how to determine whether a movie has rating > 3.2. Worse yet, the 5 fields don’t seem to contain the data needed for finding the top 10 movies viewed by users. I’m afraid you are asking the imposssible.

Comment: there is no particular reason to use hashmap just i have tried in it.and you can find the top 10 by counting the number of users have seen a each movie

Comment: Got that now, @DivagarGovindan, counting should work.

Comment: So each line of your file represents one user viewing and rating one movie? May a user rate the same movie twice, and if so, does it count twice in the condition that the user has seen at least 20 movies?

Comment: I basically agree with @DNAj’s answer, you need a data model in Java. I might go for at least two classes, `Movie` (with movie ID and title) and `Rating` (for example with user ID, age, reference to `Movie` object and rating). Maybe `User` as a separate class too.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a class representing Movie which has say 5 fields.
- Iterate over the lines of files and fill the list of Movie object.
- Use comparator or Comparable interfaces to sort list of movie objects.
- Then call list.sort().
- Instead of list you can use any collection like Set or MAP.

Hope this helps.